# Change textfield value when submit button clicked based on condition

Tags: javascript, html

Hi  I know this must be simple question I am new to javascript I wanted to implement that when a button submit was clicked the value of my two textfield will be submitted differently base in the condition but I dont know why mine is not working its not setting the value to mytext1 and mytext2. I will really appreciate any advice. Thank you

```
<script>

$(document).ready( function(){

    $('#submit').click(function() {

        var date1 = document.getElementById("temp1").value;
            var user = document.getElementById("temp2").value;

            var admin = document.getElementById("temp3").value;
            if(user!='Admin') {
                document.getElementById("mytext1").value = user;
          document.getElementById("mytext2").value = date1;

      }else {

         document.getElementById("mytext1").value = admin;
          document.getElementById("mytext2").value = date1;

      }


    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML code, and what is the meaning of ***"not working"***?

Comment: If you change the #submit button to a button type so it doesn't submit your form and at the end of your code do a #form.submit() that should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using below snippet you can differentiate whatever you want to submit differently. I've created the function using JQuery

Please provide more code in your question to understand better

```js
$(document).on('click','#submit', function() {
  var first = $('#temp1').val();
  var second = $('#temp2').val();

  var user = $('#useradmin').val();

  if (user == 'user') {
    $('#show').html(first);
    $('#showUserAdmin').html(user);
  } else {
    $('#show').html(second);
    $('#showUserAdmin').html(user);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="temp1" placeholder="will submit in User" value="Submit along with User"><br>
<input type="text" id="temp2" placeholder="will submit in Admin" value="Submit along with Admin"><br>
<select required id="useradmin">
  <option value="user">User</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>

<div id="show"></div>
<div id="showUserAdmin"></div>
```

Comment: glad it helps, you're wc

Answer (score 0):

try with "on"

```
<script>

$(document).ready( function(){

    $('document').on('click','#submit', function() {

        var date1 = document.getElementById("temp1").value;
            var user = document.getElementById("temp2").value;

            var admin = document.getElementById("temp3").value;
            if(user!='Admin') {
                document.getElementById("mytext1").value = user;
          document.getElementById("mytext2").value = date1;

      }else {

         document.getElementById("mytext1").value = admin;
          document.getElementById("mytext2").value = date1;

      }


    });
});

</script>
```